# Find a ratio of infinite product to infinite sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinite-product

How to find a limit of:
$$
lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+ib)}}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+ib)}
$$
where $a>0$ and $b>0$

The task context is Infinite Product. Please help me or just give me a tip on how to simplify the expression and approach the task.

Comment: I believe that the factor $\tfrac1n$ is missing
in the denominator,
and the expression should read
$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
{\frac{\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(a+ ib)}}
{\tfrac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(a+ib)}} 
,
$
that is, the ratio
of geometric and arithmetic means
of $n$ elements in arithmetic progression,
which is indeed equal to $\tfrac{2}{e}$
as it was stated earlier
in the recently deleted question.

Comment: I have rechecked the task and there is no $\frac{1}{n}$ factor, maybe is a typo in the textbook.

Comment: @g.kov But if You are right then this expression has a really practical use.

Comment: The question would look 
more interesting, if you 
include your thoughts 
about this practical use 
in the body of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let use arithmetic and geometric mean inequality:
$$
lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+ib)}}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+ib)} < lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+ib)/n}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+ib)} = lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0
$$
Or equivalency we can replace the denominator:
$$
lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+ib)}}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+ib)} < lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+ib)}}{n\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (a+ib)}} = lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0
$$
Notice that the equality hold **iff** $n=1$.

Comment: Using logarithms, the expression is effectively $\frac{2}{e n}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2\right)$